3x3 progressive matrix with arrows and circles
This is question number 26 from the LOG155 IQ  test. I believe the answer to be F. What do you think?



Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Answer

 The answer is G

Explanation

 At the start of each term, each circle translates one to the right. If no more space is given, the circle moves to the start of the next row. If a circle falls onto a dispenser, whether through translation, or another dispenser, the dispenser activates; generating circles in its selected directions and color. Lastly, when a circle activates a dispenser, it disappears or gets "used up", meaning it won't translate into the next term.

